# Converting a multidimensional array into another multidimensional array but with a different structure

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm having some trouble manipulating a complex array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [checklist_position] => 8
            [checklist_id] => 2
            [question_id] => 11
            [section] => 1
            [sum_a] => 332611
            [sum_b] => 566201
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [checklist_position] => 9
            [checklist_id] => 2
            [question_id] => 12
            [section] => 1
            [sum_a] => 567725
            [sum_b] => 67301
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [checklist_position] => 10
            [checklist_id] => 2
            [question_id] => 13
            [section] => 1
            [sum_a] => 20004
            [sum_b] => 38381
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [checklist_position] => 11
            [checklist_id] => 2
            [question_id] => 14
            [section] => 2
            [sum_a] => 699144
            [sum_b] => 139456
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [checklist_position] => 12
            [checklist_id] => 2
            [question_id] => 15
            [section] => 2
            [sum_a] => 791204
            [sum_b] => 336133
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [checklist_position] => 13
            [checklist_id] => 2
            [question_id] => 16
            [section] => 2
            [sum_a] => 447501
            [sum_b] => 503112
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [checklist_position] => 14
            [checklist_id] => 2
            [question_id] => 17
            [section] => 2
            [sum_a] => 651332
            [sum_b] => 803628
        )

)
```

What I'm trying to do is to convert it to an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section] => 1
            [questions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [checklist_position] => 1
                            [checklist_id] => 1
                            [question_id] => 1
                            [section] => 1
                            [sum_a] => 348659
                            [sum_b] => 273072
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [checklist_position] => 2
                            [checklist_id] => 2
                            [question_id] => 2
                            [section] => 1
                            [sum_a] => 825992
                            [sum_b] => 189190
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [section] => 2
            [questions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [checklist_position] => 1
                            [checklist_id] => 1
                            [question_id] => 1
                            [section] => 1
                            [sum_a] => 348659
                            [sum_b] => 273072
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [checklist_position] => 2
                            [checklist_id] => 2
                            [question_id] => 2
                            [section] => 1
                            [sum_a] => 825992
                            [sum_b] => 189190
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The problem is I don't know where to begin and any tip is very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Start with looping through your original array, and creating a new array.

Comment: So what is the pattern? slice array pieces (2 array each) and make new  array with different structure ?

Comment: @safarov, yes, I want to build a new array with the structure I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Patroklo's solution simplified:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $data){
    $section = $data['section'];
    $result[$section]['section'] = $section;
    $result[$section]['questions'][] = $data;
}

$result = array_values($result); // to re order
```

$array1 is your array with the current data and $result is what you expect

Comment: Thank you mrsafraz. The output is as expected. Got one more question though. Can $result start at 0? Now it starts at 1.

Comment: `$result = array_values($result);` - Check the answer again - I edited it. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll have less trouble using the section number in the keys of the arrays, like (being $array1 the first array of your question):

```
foreach($array1 as $data)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($result[data['section']))
    {
        $result[$data['section']] = array('section' => $data['section']);
    }

    $result[$data['section']['questions'][] = $data;
}
```

Haven't checked it out, but it should make it.

Comment: I think you're missing some brackets over there. It's true that I get some output, but its not as desired.

Comment: Oh, so you mean somethin like $array1 = $original_array[0]?

Comment: No, $array1 = $original_array;
You only have to loop through it, the only difference is that in the final array, instead of having the keys like -> 0, 1, 2, 3... they will be like: 1, 2